# Pandas - Pivot table based on non-numerical data

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pandas df with the following format:

```
TARGET FLAG_OWN_CAR FLAG_OWN_REALTY
0      Y            N
1      N            N
0      Y            Y
1      Y            Y
```

I would like to get the output:

```
        FLAG_OWN_CAR   FLAG_OWN_REALTY
TARGET  Y        N     Y         N
0       2        0     1         1
1       1        1     1         1
```

Following the above, I'd also like to get the values by column in % i.e. :

```
        FLAG_OWN_CAR   FLAG_OWN_REALTY
TARGET  Y        N     Y         N
0       50%      0%    25%       25%
1       25%      25%   25%       25%
```

I've tried pivot tables but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape first with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)[`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.melt('TARGET')
       .groupby(['TARGET','variable'])['value']
       .value_counts()
       .unstack([1,2], fill_value=0)
       .rename_axis((None, None), 1))
print (df)

       FLAG_OWN_CAR FLAG_OWN_REALTY    FLAG_OWN_CAR
                  Y               N  Y            N
TARGET                                             
0                 2               1  1            0
1                 1               1  1            1
```

And then dicide by `sum` per rows:

```
df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)

       FLAG_OWN_CAR FLAG_OWN_REALTY       FLAG_OWN_CAR
                  Y               N     Y            N
TARGET                                                
0              0.50            0.25  0.25         0.00
1              0.25            0.25  0.25         0.25
```

Comment: Perhaps adding `.sort_index(axis=1)` at the end might make output clear

Answer (score 2):

`pivot_table` is a possible solution:

```
i = df.melt('TARGET')
j = i.pivot_table(
    index='TARGET', columns=['variable', 'value'], aggfunc='size', fill_value=0
)
```

```
print(j)

variable FLAG_OWN_CAR    FLAG_OWN_REALTY   
value               N  Y               N  Y
TARGET                                     
0                   0  2               1  1
1                   1  1               1  1
```

Now, for the second part with the %s, you can divide by the sum (like @jezrael has done):

```
j.div(j.sum(axis=1), axis=0).astype(str).add('%')

variable FLAG_OWN_CAR        FLAG_OWN_REALTY       
value               N      Y               N      Y
TARGET                                             
0                0.0%   0.5%           0.25%  0.25%
1               0.25%  0.25%           0.25%  0.25%
```

Comment: I just realised - that the last part of your answer has the decimal places in the incorrect spot.

Comment: @KamilaAmbro what? How? It's exactly the same as the other answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `pd.concat` and `get_dummies` i.e

```
df = df.set_index('TARGET')

o = pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(df[col]) for col in df], axis=1, keys=df.columns).sum(level=0)

            FLAG_OWN_CAR    FLAG_OWN_REALTY   
                  N  Y               N  Y
TARGET                                   
0                 0  2               1  1
1                 1  1               1  1
```